# Could not build completed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, spring-mvc

I downloaded Sts spring-tool-suite-3.7.0.RELEASE-e4.5-win32-x86_64. But I create project it shows the given error .

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'sample'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-     resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
 Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

My pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.project
    project
    project
    war
    2.0

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <validation-api.version>1.0.0.GA</validation-api.version>
    <tiles-version>3.0.3</tiles-version>
</properties>



<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>       
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

            <!-- Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles-version}</version>
    </dependency>





    <!-- Validation -->

    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>


<!-- json -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
<artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20090211</version>
```

```
<!-- gson -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
 <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>



    <!--  FILE UPLOAD -->

    <dependency>  
  <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>  
  <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>  
  <version>1.2.2</version>  
 </dependency>  

 <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->  
  <dependency>  
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>  
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>  
  <version>1.3.2</version>  
 </dependency>



    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gcm</groupId>
  <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
  <!-- webservice rest -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- json parser -->
    <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.1.1</version>
   </dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.13</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
<version>0.11</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
<version>1.12</version>
 </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
  <repository>
  <id>gcm-server-repository</id>
   <url>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository /master/releases/</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>                          
<projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature    </projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                           <buildcommand> org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder </buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
```

Comment: Proxy/Firewall issue?

Comment: @khmarbaiseHow can I overcome that..

Comment: @Priyanka : Please share your pom file

Comment: @LathyI added my pom.mxl